# Upload image using selenium into a hidden element

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, xpath

```
<div class="img_selection">
<input class="js-upload hidden" name="img_upload" size="10" maxlength="250" type="file" data-dropzone="js-img_box" accept="image/*" multiple="">
<div class="js-img_progress progress hidden" title="Progress">
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

this is code used to try to upload

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys("D:\\New folder\\CODE\\locanto poster\\pics\\download.jpg")
```

I have also tried using

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='img_upload']"))).send_keys("D:\\New folder\\CODE\\locanto poster\\pics\\download.jpg")
```

I understand that I can't use CLASS_NAME because the class is a compounded class

Could someone help me please

Comment: can you confirm the url, is it public facing?

Comment: What happens when you try your line of code?